# Multiple scoping resource route

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i was create route resource and i use {post:slug} for route model binding but in some method for example update method, i want to use {post:id} for route model binding and keep the other method to use {post:slug}

How to implement it? Is it possible to add multiple scope

this is my code

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/posts', DashboardPostController::class)->scoped(['post' => 'slug']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use resources without update:

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/posts', DashboardPostController::class)->scoped(['post', 'slug'])->except('update');
```

and then:

```
Route::put('dashboard/posts/{posts:id}, [ DashboardPostController::class => 'update');
```